# Angular Input Mask to only disable numbers

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create an input mask.

I want delete and arrow key functionality plus all the other keys except 1 2 3 4 5 6. I'm using 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 as hotkeys for a scheduling app. Is it possible in angular to create a mask that just disables the numbers one through six?

```
<input pattern="regex"> <!-- not working because it only fires after submit -->
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask

Comment: ng-keypress is all I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" ng-keypress="keyPressed($event)">
```

In controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.keyPressed = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode >= 49 && e.keyCode <= 54) { 
             event.preventDefault();
        } else {
             // do your logic
        }
    }
}
```

You can do with `ng-pattern` attribute but it allows the character and do the validation but your requirement is to disable characters.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, this is also disabling A B C D E F (first 6 letters of the alphabet)

Comment: (e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 102) is causing the A B C D E F error for some reason

Comment: a = 97
b = 98
c = 99
d = 100
e = 101
f = 102
according to http://www.expandinghead.net/keycode.html. Somehow those keycodes break it. I guess there's no support for numpads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular `ng-pattern` to achieve this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="check" name="check" ng-pattern="/^[^1-6.]*$/">
<small class="error" ng-show="exampleForm.check.$error.pattern">Invalid pattern.</small>
```

Dynamically checks for invalid key enter not on submit.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I tried it and I think it's only firing after hitting the submit button. Thank you anyway for your help :)

Comment: Who told that it only works with submit? You can do it on change too.